# Is this syntax an object definition or an object template?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Recently I saw in TypeScript the below declaration that looks like to be more a JavaScript syntax:

```
markers: { [id:string]: mapboxgl.Marker } = {}
```

`mapboxgl.Marker` is a class, so it looks like it will hold objects of that type per key. The assignment is this:

```
this.markers[marcador.id] = marker;
```

I'm not familiar with that notation and trying to understand how it works since as far as I know objects define properties and values as key/value pair, but I'm seeing `[key:type]: [valueType]`. I haven't found something like that researching in internet.

Comment: What `markers:` is a part of?

Comment: Objects are not necessarily key/value pairs. `{"happy"}` is for instance an object as is `{}`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I'm not sure if I follow your first example. That's a string in a block statement, no?

Comment: That's an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

Comment: If you simply correlate that with a value, does that change your perception? `let cheese = {"chedder"};`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This `{"cheddar"}` is not valid syntax. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBTRFEwLwwN4CIGIBMCBDAJxwF8g

Comment: @AlexWayne it is when you view the JavaScript that this TypeScript all becomes; so probably my differing perspective but yes we are both right in a sense.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss What? The only way that's valid is when the `{}` are block scopers, and there's not object types involved at all https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4IgxgFgpgJjCGAnEBfIA which isn't what this question seems to be about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an index signature. [See the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

```
type Foo = { [myKey: string]: number }
```

In that snippet, `string` is the type of each property key, `number` is the value of property, and `myKey` is just a label.

The label isn't used for any type enforcement really, but it's provided as hints for your code editor when reporting types.

And what it means that that you may index that type with *any* string.